# vim-latex always moves the cursor to the beginning of the line upon compilation. How do I stop this?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I have posted this question to [/r/vim](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/s2ocv/vimlatex_moves_my_cursor_on_compile/), with no success. The title basically explains the situation: every time I compile with `<leader>ll`, Vim moves my cursor to the beginning of the line, which is really annoying!

My `vimrc` can be found at http://pastebin.com/7F8hKyHs. Does anyone have any suggestions?